# Why does my insertion sort algorithm only work with single digit integers?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, arraylist

I've wrote a simple insertion sort algorithm for fun. It appears to be working just fine with one problem, it only works when all items in the array (the thing its trying to sort) are single digit integers. If an element is a multi-digit integer, it sorts everything up to that integer, then stops and throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException.`

Note: Just so you understand the source code, the way my program works is like this: I pass the `InsertionSort` class a primative `int` array in construction. I then convert that to the `ArrayList list`. I know that the `ArrayList list` has the correct values copied over because I print it out and it matches up.

**Example Runs:**

*Working:*

`{ 9, 2, 8, 5, 1, 6, 6, 7, 1}; //works perfectly` **->**

```
Unsorted List: [9, 2, 8, 5, 1, 6, 6, 7, 1]
Step 1: [9]
Step 2: [2, 9]
Step 3: [2, 8, 9]
Step 4: [2, 5, 8, 9]
Step 5: [1, 2, 5, 8, 9]
Step 6: [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9]
Step 7: [1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9]
Step 8: [1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Step 9: [1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Sorted List: [1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

*Not Working:*

`{ 9, 2, 8, 5, 1, 6, 6, 7, 1, 22, 823, 30, 244, 45, 5}; //doesn't work` **->**

```
Unsorted List: [9, 2, 8, 5, 1, 6, 6, 7, 1, 22, 823, 30, 244, 45, 5]
Step 1: [9]
Step 2: [2, 9]
Step 3: [2, 8, 9]
Step 4: [2, 5, 8, 9]
Step 5: [1, 2, 5, 8, 9]
Step 6: [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9]
Step 7: [1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9]
Step 8: [1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Step 9: [1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9]
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 9, Size: 9
Sorted List: [1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at InsertionSort.sort(InsertionSort.java:41)
    at Executer.main(Executer.java:7)
```

**Here is the relevant sorting code:**

```
static ArrayList<Integer> list = new<Integer> ArrayList();
static ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new<Integer> ArrayList();

public static int[] sort() {
    int s = 0;
    System.out.println("Unsorted List: " + list.toString());

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        s++;
            if (i == 0) {
                list2.add(list.get(i));
                System.out.println("Step " + s + ": " + list2.toString());
                continue;

            } else {
                int z = 0;
                while (list2.get(z) < list.get(i)) {
                    z++;
                }

                list2.add(z, list.get(i));

            }
            System.out.println("Step " + s + ": " + list2.toString());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    System.out.println("Sorted List: " + list2.toString());

    return toPrimative(list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]));
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you should do some debugging...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I tried adding some print statements and things. I've also read JavaDoc about ArrayList. To be honest, I don't really know how to use the eclipse debugger. Could you recommend a debugger procedure? (Where to add print statements, etc.)

Comment: Learning to use the debugger is just as important as learning the language.  Spend some time on that. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_debugging_program.htm

Comment: @OldProgrammer okay thank you for the link and advice. You are 100% right I will definitely learn the debugger. I've been meaning to do that for some time now, just never really needed it since most of my programs are very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with single or multi digit numbers, in first example you were just lucky to have the biggest number as a first element in a list. There is an obvious mistake when you're choosing a position for the next element:

```
int z = 0;
while (list2.get(z) < list.get(i)) {
    z++;
}
```

You increment index but don't do bounds check, so when it comes to number 22 you get an exception. The correct one would be

```
while (list2.get(z) < list.get(i) && z <= list2.size())
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, I'll add that bit to the loop. Better then my solution of : `if(z >= list2.size()) { z--; break; }`

Answer (score 2):

Mind debug. Problem is here:

```
while (list2.get(z) < list.get(i)) {
                    z++;
                }
```

z exceeds list2 count if new value is the biggest.
First value 9 in small numbers example hid this problem.

I hope that solution is clear enough

Comment: Thank you! Working now (almost, found another issue but I think I can deal with that).